# Infinite loop display iteration database entries

Tags: javascript, php, database, animation

I have php code,that fetch and show entries from database.I need to display them while they shuffling until something happened /pressing a button ect./

something like this-  http://jsfiddle.net/ZDsMa/1/

here is my code

```
<?php
$winners = [];
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin", "lottary");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $firstname = $row['first_name'];
    $lastName = $row['last_name'];
    $points = $row['point'];
    $all =$id.' '.$firstname. ' '.$lastName. ' '.$points;


    ?>
    <input class="form-control" size="40" name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $all; ?>">

<?php }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: is this the case ? user sends request and while response from server is awaited run some sort of number counter as in keep user interested.

Comment: If you're linking to an example of what you want to do, what's your question?  What's stopping you from using that example and building your application?  Have you made some attempt which didn't work in some way?

Comment: Just a head note since long ago animated loading gifs one of those the go in circle have been substituted for counters because who knows how long it might take it could be 30 before we even blink for the second time. Consider looking into UI side with css and all that is killed on response.

Comment: I assume you want the counter to reflect the currently resulted user number. That query should take milli seconds and building the HTML another couple of milli seconds. Why bother with a counter in front of a user.

Comment: Or if its going to take an hour to present all the data, you are presenting to much for any user to bother looking at, see pagination

Comment: i want a infinite loop which shuffle data entries until pressing a button will break the loop and show one entry.

Comment: @murphy_86: An "infinite loop" probably isn't the right term then.  You want JavaScript code which is set on a very small interval (see `setInterval`) which updates the UI.  And you want JavaScript which responds to a button click and clears that interval.

Comment: exactly.i need js script to do it , but i don`t know js and a need help with this

Comment: @murphy_86: If the problem is that you don't know JavaScript then the solution is to start with some tutorials on JavaScript.  Stack Overflow does not provide personal tutoring services.  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Here is jquery script that shuffle database entries,with stop/start button

```
<div class="demo">
     <div id="roll"></div><input type="hidden" id="mid" value="">
     <p><input type="button" class="btn" id="start" value="Start"> <input type="button" class="btn" id="stop" value="Stop"></p>
     <div id="result"></div>
  </div>


start_btn.click(function(){
        $.getJSON('data.php',function(json){
            if(json){
                //var obj = eval(json);//By eval () function can be converted into JSON string object
                var len = json.length;
                _gogo = setInterval(function(){
                    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
                    //var id = obj[num]['id'];
                    var id = json[num].id;
                    //var v = obj[num]['mobile'];
                    var v = json[num].mobile;
                    $("#roll").html(v);
                    $("#mid").val(id);
                },100);
                stop_btn.show();
                start_btn.hide();
            }else{
                $("#roll").html('System can not find the data source, first import the data.');
            }
        });
        //_gogo = setInterval(show_number,100);
    });});
stop_btn.click(function(){ 
        clearInterval(_gogo); 
        var mid = $("#mid").val(); 
        $.post("data.php?action=ok",{id:mid},function(msg){ 
            if(msg==1){ 
                var mobile = $("#roll").html(); 
                $("#result").append("<p>"+mobile+"</p>"); 
            } 
            stop_btn.hide(); 
            start_btn.show(); 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:
maybe that work
just replace while by foreach

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "admin", "lottary");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$fetch = $result->fetch_array();
foreach($fetch as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $firstname = $row['first_name'];
    $lastName = $row['last_name'];
    $points = $row['point'];
    $all = $id.' '.$firstname. ' '.$lastName. ' '.$points;
    ?>
    <input class="form-control" size="40" name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $all; ?>">

<?php 
}
$conn->close();
?>
```